# NSPredicate Memory Issues

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, nspredicate

So I am trying to fix this really annoying bug. If I filter my array like the ideal version with NSPredicate, I will get EXC_BAD_ACCESS because it tries to call release on the object passed in as the delegate an extra time. If I filter with the working version, it works fine. I thought these two implementations were identical. Where am I going wrong? I know the predicate way is the way to go, just can't get it to work correctly.

```
// Ideal version
- (NSArray *)foosWithDelegate:(id)delegate {
    return [foos filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"delegate = %@", delegate]];
}

// Working version
- (NSArray *)foosWithDelegate:(id)delegate {
    NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (MYFoo *foo in foos) {
        if (foo.delegate == delegate) {
            [results addObject:foo];
        }
    }

    if ([results count] == 0) {
        [results release];
        return nil;
    }

    return [results autorelease];
}
```

`foos` is an ivar. The `MYFoo` class has a property for delegate that is `assign`. The issue still happens even if `foos` is empty.

Comment: Sample works for me with no `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Would you post a minimal test case that produces the same error, in particular showing the code around the `foosWithDelegate` invocation?

Comment: Here is [a sample project](http://github.com/samsoffes/predicate-test). It doesn't crash because the view controller is still in memory. If this was in a navigation controller scenario, it would crash when you hit back and the view controller was released.

You can see that the retain count changes after the ideal version of the method and does not with the working version of the method.

Comment: Never figured it out. Ended up going another way.

Answer (score 1):

In your PredicateTestViewController's dealloc method, you should be releasing foos, not deallocating them.

```
// Your code in PredicateTestViewController.m
- (void)dealloc
{
    [foos dealloc];
    [super dealloc];
}

// Your new code in PredicateTestViewController.m
- (void)dealloc
{
    [foos release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: This was a typeo and has nothing to do with the issue in the question.

Comment: The typeo has been corrected http://github.com/samsoffes/predicate-test/commit/cb4f6bde6cabc9fc4a57d05b7562ea2a154a9ff9